# How can I get all the contents between two pattern using python regular expression?

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

Following content is the file I have:

```
>AWFG:AW as EWFA
ASEGEGAGWGEAH
AWGGWAHEDSFH
AWFGHWF
>XWAF:AE SEQUEL
ADAFFAGAWAFAFWFGAGWAWDDA
ADWFWAGAWDAASASFAWGAFWGG
AWFAGAWWGGAWGGW
>YADF:ADthe  AFWFGA
WADGGGWAGAWWGGAW
```

In this file, I need to get output like following:

```
>XWAF:AE SEQUEL
ADAFFAGAWAFAFWFGAGWAWDDA
ADWFWAGAWDAASASFAWGAFWGG
AWFAGAWWGGAWGGW
```

Now i want to get the above mentioned output by matching pattern `>XWAF:AE` as start pattern and all the contents untill next `>` end pattern.

I tried many possible ways, but were not able to solve this for long time since I am a beginner in python.

Comment: Please post what you've tried if you want debugging help.

Comment: I've rolled the edits back. You can't go editing text in a regex question! The OP may say "please ignore <xyz> formatting" but the onus is on them to fix it.

Comment: Please see [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and edit your post appropriately. It's hard for me to understand why you keep characters in the text and then tell readers to ignore them; why don't you simply remove it yourself in the question? You can [edit] your post to clarify.

Comment: @roganjosh ... the `>` is the "special" quoting character - the OP was unable to print it "as is" because the formatting interpreted the text as "citation" with it in front - hence he added the `*` in front and told ppl to ignore it ....

Comment: @PatrickArtner but it wouldn't be if they encapsulated the whole thing in code formatting?

Comment: @roganjosh Thanks for altering my question. I will keep all your suggestions before posting next question. As mentioned by PatrickArtner I was facing that problem. Since I am new to stackoverflow, I wasn't knowing the code formatting. But now I understood and follow this in future. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You can try this**

```
^>XWAF:AE[\w\W]*?(?=>)
```

> Explanation

- `^` - Anchor to start of string.
- `>XAWF:AF` - Matches `>XAWF:AF`.
- `[\w\W]*?` - Matches any character  zero or more time (lazy mode).
- `(?=>)` - Positive look ahead matches `>`.

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/XXQ991/1/)

Comment: `[^>]+` is simpler than `[\w\W]*?`

Comment: @Toto yeah sure! thanks for suggestion :)